# Make changes in \vendor\magento\module-cookie\Block\Html\Notices.php

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I want do do changes in the following file:

```
\vendor\magento\module-cookie\Block\Html\Notices.php
```

How can I stop that file from being overwritten when doing upgrades in the future? Can I override it in some way, e.g. move it to the theme structure?

Thanks!

Comment: you can directly not change this file you can just overwritten in your custom create extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your custom module and add rewrite code in your custom module, please try following way.

Create custom module Vendor/Module

**/app/code/Vendor/Module**

**|_ composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "vendor/module-module",
    "description": "",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "TestModule",
            "email": "info@test.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Vendor\\Module\\": ""
        },
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

**|_registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

**|_ etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

**|_ etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Vendor\Module\Block\Html\Notices" type="Magento\Cookie\Block\Html\Notices" />
</config>
```

**|_ Block/Html/Notices.php** (Please add your overrited code in this file )

```
<?php

/**
 * Frontend form key content block
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Html;

class Notices extends \Magento\Cookie\Block\Html\Notices
{

    public function getPrivacyPolicyLink()
    {
        return $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl('privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode');
    }
}
```

Please try this way and let me know if any issue.

Comment: I did exactly like this, just changed the Vendor\Module to my namespace, and changed "privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode"  to "privacy-policy" in the Notices.php file but it still shows the link to "privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode"